# RxJS v6 migration, I don't understand what wrong?

Tags: angular, rxjs6

I updated to Angular 6. Did not install rxjs-compat.
Change in my code

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
```

to

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
```

and so on.

But if I do ng serve I get an error

```
ERROR in node_modules/primeng/components/accordion/accordion.d.ts(4,10): error TS2305: Module '"../JetBrains/WebstormProjects/test5/node_modules/rxjs/Subscription"' has no exported member 'Subscription'.
node_modules/primeng/components/common/confirmationservice.d.ts(1,10): error TS2305: Module '"../JetBrains/WebstormProjects/test5/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
node_modules/primeng/components/common/messageservice.d.ts(1,10): error TS2305: Module '".../JetBrains/WebstormProjects/test5/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
...
```

and so on.

How to fix these errors?

Comment: Probably because primeng version of 'rxjs' isn't up to date yet, or maybe it is and your primeng isnt up to date.

Comment: Oh, for sure! I have the latest version of PrimeNg, so I have only one way, it's use rxjs-compat. Thanks a lot!

Comment: dont ng server restart the npm.

Comment: Is there any solution for this problem as of now. Can anyone help please

Answer (score 0):

Please try running the following command its works for me in Angular 8.

```
npm install --save-dev rxjs-compat
```